# Jest: Spy on react-redux calls (useDispatch)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I want to check if dispatch by react-redux has been called.
In debug mode, I can see that the respective line of code is executed, so dispatch is actually called but in my jest test the result is always 0 calls.
What would be the proper way to do this?

```
const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();

jest.doMock('react-redux', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
  useDispatch: () => mockDispatchFn,
}));

...


expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

`doMock` and `requireActual` are not really reliable especially for things that might already be caught by other modules in their constants or through function closures. Better to avoid it instead of searching how to make it working.

**Option 1.** Better one.

Redux docs [are pretty opinionated](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#setting-up-a-reusable-test-render-function) here:

> Prefer writing integration tests with everything working together. For a React app using Redux, render a `<Provider>` with a real store instance wrapping the components being tested. Interactions with the page being tested should use real Redux logic, with API calls mocked out so app code doesn't have to change, and assert that the UI is updated appropriately.

It means:

1. Real store reducer
2. to mock store data we will call `dispatch` on that story with related action creators `mockedStore.dispatch(someDataLoadedAction(someMockedData))`
3. instead of checking whether `dispatch` has been called we, depending on what should happen, will:
   a. either validate new store state through selectors("after clicking this button in Component1 we expect Redux's selector `getSomeFlag` to return true") b. or  validating something else happened(network call has been sent with expected parameters, document title has been changed, navigation has occured etc)
   c. or validating our component has been updated according to new store's state

Something like this:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
// store preparation
store.dispatch(somethingLoadedSuccess(mock1));
store.dispatch(somethingChanged(someMock2));
// rendering component 
const { getByRole, getByText } = render(<Provider store={store}>
  <ComopnentUnderTest prop1="a" prop2={something} />
</Provide>);
// simulating some scenario 
fireEvent.click(getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }));
// asserting
expect(someSelector1(store.getState())).toBe(42);
expect(getByText('Saved successfully')).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(mockedNetworkLayer.isDone()).toBe(true);
```

**Option 2.** Tricky and not that reliable.

Using `redux-mock-store` you can easily check which actions has been dispatched, however with this approach:

1. you cannot change Redux state during the test so will be unable to test some cases
2. you will need to mock store tree with static data; tests become fragile - if you ever do internal refactoring of store's structure and update correctly all the selectors, you will also need to update all the mocked static data across the tests to make them passing again; tests become unreliable - if you ever do internal refactoring of store's structure and *miss to update* selectors accordingly, tests will still be passing though app will be broken

```
// store preparation
const store = configureStore([thunk])(staticDataMockForAStore);
// rendering component 
const { getByRole, getByText } = render(<Provider store={store}>
  <ComopnentUnderTest prop1="a" prop2={something} />
</Provide>);
// simulating some scenario 
fireEvent.click(getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' }));
// asserting
expect(store.getActions()).toContainEqual({
  type: 'SOME_ACTION_TYPE',
  value1: 1,
  value2: 'a'
});
```

Also for that approach to assert on actions dispatched you may need [`expect.objectContaining`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) to ignore some properties with random data(UUID etc)